# different ways to manage high volume data and show the data in the UI screen or search

Tags: java, spring, oracle

I am working in java and wanted to know the best possible ways to manage high volume data when retrieving from the database(oracle) and displaying the records in UI screen or searching the data in the database from the UI screen developed using java. This was one of the interview question and I felt it is quite challenging and would be helpful for other too in future reference.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Pagination and Sorting [PagingAndSortingRepository](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/repository/PagingAndSortingRepository.html) of Spring Data. Which accepts

```
(pageNo, pageSize, sortBy).
```

As per my opinion. You have to first get the total number of records from the database and then decide the chunk size and sorting parameter.
This will be something like:

```
Total number of rows: 100000;
(20, 100000, ASC)
```

This chunk size is basically the total pages in a hit. So this can be one of the way to large data in UI.